# How do I use the .equalsIgnoreCase() method in a while loop that will only let the user enter letters A-Z and numbers 0-9 in Java?

Tags: java

How do I use the `.equalsIgnoreCase()` method in a while loop that will only let the user enter letters A-Z and numbers 0-9? The `referenceNumber` is a `String`.

```
while (referenceNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(A-Z) && referenceNumber(0-9))
{
    System.out.println("customer reference number: " + referenceNumber);
}
```

Comment: You don't. Read the manual page to see what it does. You need to use a regular express. Search again looking for java regular expressions.

Comment: Anyway, if your `while` loop condition was met, your programme would never end. You should read a little more about loops before using them [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm), [Java For Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), [Java While and Do-While Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: How can I use a string literal to validate a user entered string with a lower case letter followed by six digits?

Answer (score 2):

You won't, as - I think - you want to validate the string.

Use [`String.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) for this:

```
boolean isOk = referenceNumber.matches("[0-9A-Z]+");
```

This will only return true if the `referenceNumber`'s contents are only from the set of A through Z and/or 0 through 9 inclusive.

Comment: Can methods not be placed in the conditions of while loops?

Comment: You can, but why, if there is a much simpler solution? :-)